# SystemJsNgModuleLoader "System not defined"

Tags: angular, .net-core

I'm using Angular 2 with .Net Core and Webpack. I am trying to load dynamically modules into my application. Here is the App Component:

```js
//our root app component
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {
 Component,
 ViewContainerRef,
 Compiler,
 ComponentFactory,
 ComponentFactoryResolver,
 ModuleWithComponentFactories,
 ComponentRef,
 ReflectiveInjector,
 SystemJsNgModuleLoader,
 AfterViewInit,
 OnInit,
 NgModuleFactory
} from '@angular/core';

export class ModuleNode { modulePath: string; componentName: string; }

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: require('./app.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./app.component.css')]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

 widgetConfig: string;
 module: ModuleNode;
 cmpRef: ComponentRef<any>;

 constructor(private viewref: ViewContainerRef,
  private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
  private loader: SystemJsNgModuleLoader,
  private compiler: Compiler) {
  this.module = new ModuleNode();
  this.module.modulePath = "./dynamic.module";
  this.module.componentName = "TestComponent";
 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.openWebApp(this.module);
 }

 ngOnInit() {
  
 }


 openWebApp(menu: any) {
  this.loader.load(menu.modulePath)  // load the module and its components
   .then((modFac) => {
    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync<any>(modFac.moduleType)

     .then((factory: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
      return factory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType.name === menu.componentName);
     })
     .then(cmpFactory => {

      // need to instantiate the Module so we can use it as the provider for the new component
      let modRef = modFac.create(this.viewref.parentInjector);
      this.cmpRef = this.viewref.createComponent(cmpFactory, 0, modRef.injector);
      // done, now Module and main Component are known to NG2

     });
   });
 }

 ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.cmpRef) {
   this.cmpRef.destroy();
  }
 }
}
```

At "this.loader.load(menu.modulePath)" i get an Error "System is not defined".
As i know it could be a part of SystemJs that could be missing but In .Net Core and Webpack it should not be anymore required. Am i right?

Comment: Which version webpack are you using?

Comment: My Versions are:
webpack: 1.12.14, webpack-externals-plugin: 1.0.0, webpack-hot-middleware: 2.10.0, webpack-merge: 0.14.1,

Comment: You need webpack2 and check this thread https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to yurzui,
i changed webpack to version 2 and the error disappeared.

But now i have a problem to find the module. I get "vendor.js:59947 EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot find module './dynamic.module'."

I also tried './dynamic.module.ts','./ClientApp/app/components/app/dynamic.module.ts' 
and require("./dynamic.module.ts") before loading from File.